# Do modern RAFT implementations assume that nodes trust each other?

Tags: consensus

I'm starting to dig into the RAFT consensus algorithm and I wanted to clarify something pretty basic: it seems like RAFT operates on the assumptions that 1) each node trusts all the other nodes and that 2) nodes would not have a failure mode where they would incorrectly identify themselves as a leader from a higher term.

My understanding is that 2 is prevented if 1 is true and if RAFT is correctly implemented, because no node would identify itself as a leader without a quorum. In a partition scenario, the worst case is that there are two partitions of unequal size, and so only nodes in one of the partitions should ever be able to be elected leader.

So I think my question is really just to get some clarity on whether RAFT algorithms rely on trusting the messages received from other cluster members.

Answer (score 1):

A common assumption is "Messages are delivered without corruption" - which means nodes trust each other. So you are right!

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. The question asks about *modern* implementations. Can you give [*references*](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) to back up your affirmation? Release dates would be a welcome convenience - especially in years to come.